# retrieving the listening port during buildProtocol

Tags: python, twisted

i'm modifying the ServerFactory's buildProtocol method, basically the factory listens in at port 11000 and 12000, and I have two protocols, one for port each port.  I'm trying to retrieve the port that the client used to listen in so that I can instantiate the correct protocol.

ex. client listens in at port 11000, protocol 1 is instantiated.  client listens in at port 12000, protocol 2 is instantiated.

i think this can be only done in the buildProtocol stage, is there a way to determine which port was used to connect?  the address parameter used by buildProtocol is the client address, I need the server port.

pseudo code:

```
def buildProtocol(self, address):
  if address connects at port 11000:
    proto = TransformProtocol()
  else:
    proto = TransformProtocol2()
  proto.factory = self
  return proto
```

Comment: A small example would be helpful since it's hard to visualize your issue.  It's also a little confusing when you say "ex. client listens at port 11000..."  Do you mean the server (generally, servers are doing the listening)?

Comment: hey gerrat, yeah the server is listening in at 11000 and 12000.  what i would like to do is have separate protocols for each port.  for example, protocol1 at port 11000 will capitalize all the text that the client sends, while protocol2 at port 12000 will transform all the text that the client sends to lowercase..  so basically there is one factory instance, but two different protocols for each of the two ports.

Comment: Protocols are completely unrelated to ports. You should subclass your Factory to have two classes with different functionality. Then bind them to ports as you desire.

Comment: it's an exercise from a twisted tutorial, otherwise i'd just have two factory instances each with a different protocol and it would be done.

Comment: How one factory instance can listen two ports? Can you give link for this exercise? Thnx

Comment: one factory can listen to two ports through reactor.listenTCP http://paste.pocoo.org/show/295563/

Answer (score 0):

I think, you may need to use Twisted services:
[link text](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tutorial/protocol.html)

You code become something like:

```
from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from twisted.protocols import basic

class UpperCaseProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):
    def lineReceived(self, line):
        self.transport.write(line.upper() + '\r\n')
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class LowerCaseProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):
    def lineReceived(self, line):
        self.transport.write(line.lower() + '\r\n')
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class LineCaseService(service.Service):

    def getFactory(self, p):
        f = protocol.ServerFactory()
        f.protocol = p
        return f

application = service.Application('LineCase')
f = LineCaseService()

serviceCollection = service.IServiceCollection(application)
internet.TCPServer(11000,f.getFactory(UpperCaseProtocol)).setServiceParent(serviceCollection)
internet.TCPServer(12000,f.getFactory(LowerCaseProtocol)).setServiceParent(serviceCollection)
```

But, here we have two factory instances.

Comment: Krondo introduction to asynchronous programming is great, but, I think, my solution is more clear and Twisted's-style. Protocol is the proper place for specific data manipulatin logic (upper, lower). A Factory is the proper place for data that you want to make available to the protocol instances, since the protocol instances are garbage collected when the connection is closed. Try to run this example: twistd -y server.tac (the name of example file), telnet localhost 11000

Comment: You may also read gread Twisted tutorial "Twisted From Scratch": http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tutorial/index.html

Comment: exercise number 3: "Use the same instance of the TransformService for both." Author mean service, not a Factory.

Comment: `LineCaseService` implements neither `startService` nor `stopService`, and is never added to the service hierarchy.  For that matter, its `getFactory` method never refers to `self`.  There's no reason for it to be a service; in fact, there's no reason that it isn't just a global `getFactory` function, with no state.